# Array How would you add a digit to the same location as its value?

Tags: java, arrays, location

The input comes as a `String "543210"`.
The code extracts each character using the `charAt` method and place them one after the other in a specific array location that corresponds to the value of the number. 
`charAt(0) = 5` means that 5 should go into`arrayLocation 5`.
It doesnt seem to work. I even tried with `arrayLists`.

```
public class HugeInteger {

    private String digits;

    int[] arrayToStoreTheDigits = new int[6];

    public HugeInteger(String digits) {

        this.digits = digits;
        add();


    }

    public void add() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            arrayToStoreTheDigits[digits.charAt(i)] = digits.charAt(i);
            System.out.println(digits.charAt(i));
        }

    }

    public String toString() {

        return "" + arrayToStoreTheDigits + "/ " + digits.charAt(2);
    }

}

package Exercise8_17_HugeIntegers;

public class HugeIntegertester {
    // static HugeInteger huge;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HugeInteger huge = new HugeInteger("543210");

    System.out.println(huge.toString());

    }




}
```

Comment: using `ArrayList` is not an option?

Comment: Did you want to write that it does not *seem* to work? What is wrong?

Comment: It doesnt work was my comment. sorry i misstyped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but I suspect the problem is here:

```
arrayToStoreTheDigits[digits.charAt(i)] = digits.charAt(i);
```

If `digits.charAt(i)` is `'5'` that has an *integer* value of 53, as that's the UTF-16 code unit for the character `'5'`. If you're trying to extract its value when viewed as a digit, you need to use `Character.digit`. Alternatively you could just subtract `'0'` if you really only care about 0-9, and are confident there will be no other characters.

So you could write your code like this:

```
char c = digits.charAt(i);
arrayToStoreTheDigits[c - '0'] = c;
```

Note that due to this initialization:

```
int[] arrayToStoreTheDigits = new int[6];
```

... your code will fail if it ever sees a value of `'6'` or greater.

Additionally, if you want to use all the characters in `digits`, your loop should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < digits.length(); i++)
```

Overall this is a very odd thing to want to do - because the *only* values valid for array element 1 (for example) will be `'1'` (if the digit is present) or 0 (the default, if it's not). In particular, this loses *all* information about the position in which the digits occurred. If the class is meant to be similar to `BigInteger`, you should be writing something much more like this:

```
arrayToStoreTheDigits = new int[digits.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < arrayToStoreTheDigits.length; i++)
{
    // TODO: Digit validation
    arrayToStoreTheDigits[i] = digits.charAt(i) - '0';
}
```

So that after passing in `"543210"` you'd have an array of `{ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 }`. That's now *useful* information.

Comment: Yes, the UTF -16 code, thats what i keep getting. I'll try the Character.digit. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Problem exists with your loop :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {  // condition shoule be i < 6
    // arrayToStoreTheDigits[digits.charAt(i)] = digits.charAt(i); // convert String to integer
    // shoule be
    arrayToStoreTheDigits[Integer.parseInt(digits.charAt(i))] = Integer.parseInt(digits.charAt(i));
    System.out.println(digits.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work ;). But i understand your point because i tried to implement a parser.